# Can I have individual Xtend files intermingled with my Java source files in a Spring project?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, xtext

In the Xtext [documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/xtend/) I can only find how to set up an Xtend-only project.

But I have a Spring MVC project that I want to incorporate Xtend into.

Is it possible to have individual Xtend files intermingled with my Java source files in a Spring project?

Or does the Xtend project need to be a separate Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1):

It just needs the Xtext nature and the following three jars on the classpath:

- org.eclipse.xtext.xtend2.lib
- org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.lib
- com.google.collect

You find them in the plugins folder of your eclipse installation.